# Code signing for SmartScreen

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, smartscreen

I'm trying to find an appropiate `code signing` for my company in order to sign our applications to not be detected as malicious, as we are not! :)

I'm facing a lot of certificates, for example, the one from [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/en/uk/code-signing/). This price varies a lot from the one from [Comodo](https://www.comodo.com/business-security/code-signing-certificates/code-signing.php).

Can anyone tell me the real difference between both of them? I'm getting a bit lost...